# How to display PNG image binary result as image in HTML with Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this [AI service](https://docs.vanceai.com/#download-result) API which allows me edit images. I upload an image, then process applying an edition provided by this API service and finally the result is for download, this is the code:

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append("api_token", "XXXXXXX1234AAAAAA");
form.append("trans_id", "XXXXBBBBVVVVVVVV"); //processed image ID

var settings = {
  "url": "https://api-service.vanceai.com/web_api/v1/download?api_token=XXXXXXX1234AAAAAA",
  "method": "POST",
  "timeout": 0,
  "processData": false,
  "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
  "contentType": false,
  "data": form
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
        console.log(response); // binary result
});
```

This is the binary result which is not a Blob:

[image]

I want to display this in an img tag:

```
<img id="ml" src="">
```

I tried with these methods:

```
$("#ml").attr("src",'data:image/png;base64,'+ btoa(response) );

$("#ml").attr("src",'data:image/png;base64,'+ btoa(encodeURIComponent(response)) );

$("#ml").attr("src",'data:image/png;base64,'+ btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(response))) );
```

But I get these errors:

[image]

or

[image]

where base64 code doesn't display correctly.

I also tried converting to Blob:

```
var blob = new Blob([response], {type: 'image/png'});
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
           $('#ml').attr('src', e.target.result);
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
```

But I get the same error:

[image]

I used a library: https://github.com/dankogai/js-base64

```
var emk = Base64.encode(response);
$("#ml").attr("src",'data:image/png;base64,'+ emk );
```

But the result is the same.

Finally I also tried to convert this result to Arraybuffer:

```
  var ab = new ArrayBuffer(response.length);
  var bb = new Blob([ab],{type: "image/png"});

  var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(bb); 
      reader.onloadend = function() {
      var base64data = reader.result;                
          //console.log(base64data);

          $("#ml").attr("src",base64data);
      }
```

But it's the same error:

[image]

I'd like to receive your help.

Comment: `<img id="ml" src="https://api-service.vanceai.com/web_api/v1/download?api_token=XXXXXXX1234AAAAAA&trans_id=XXXXBBBBVVVVVVVV">` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to consume that response as binary data, not as UTF-8 text.
To do so, since you use jQuery's [`ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method, you need to pass a new field in the `settings` object:

```js
var settings = {
  "url": "https://api-service.vanceai.com/web_api/v1/download?api_token=XXXXXXX1234AAAAAA",
  "method": "POST",
  "timeout": 0,
  "processData": false,
  "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
  "contentType": false,
  "data": form,
  // Add this new field to consume the response a binary data
  xhrFields: {
    responseType: "blob"
  }
};
```

Then in your `done` callback, `response` will be a `Blob` object. You will be able to create a symlink to that `Blob`'s data with the `URL.createObjectURL()` method. If after displaying that image you don't need the `Blob` data anymore, you can revoke the symlink.

```js
$.ajax(settings).then((response) => {
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(response);
  $("#ml")
    .prop("src", url)
    .one("load", () => URL.revokeObjectURL(url));
});
```

Comment: It shows me an error in console ``Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed.``

Comment: Oh sorry I had a typo, it's `xhrFields` with an `s`.

Comment: It shows me another error in console: ``Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'responseText' property from 'XMLHttpRequest': The value is only accessible if the object's 'responseType' is '' or 'text' (was 'blob').``

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Is there anything in your code that tries to read the response as text? Nothing in mine should trigger this error. Can you provide the trace of that error?

Comment: I'm using Jquery 2.0.0

Comment: <tongue-in-cheek>Like, as a celebration for its 10 years anniversary (in 2 months)?</tongue-in-cheek> You might want to use a newer version, a lot of bugs have been fixed since then, some quite critical, even security wise.